# Google Maps API v3 over HTTPS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a https version of the google maps api v3? I have a site that uses https and am getting annoying mixed secure and non-secure content errors in IE. I read that in v2 you had to pay to get this, but haven't seen anything for v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

As of [March 2011](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=591#c134)

> The Maps API v3, Static Maps API, and Maps API Web Services are now
>   available to all developers over https:

---

This is one of [my big problems with Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#ssl). If you want to access Google Maps javascript via https you have to sign up as a [Google Maps Premier customer](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html).

There is a [Google Maps API issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=591&q=https&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) on the topic with lots of mutinous comments, but the [final word](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=591&q=https&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal#c68) from Google is that they will not be supporting this functionality in the free API.

This particular problem is close to my heart as I have spent the last few days porting one of our projects over to [Bing Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx) (it does support https).

Comment: Very sad, I guess I'll have to switch over to bing maps as well. It just sucks because I already finished coding up the solution w/google maps!

Comment: The Google Maps JavaScript API v3, Google Static Maps API, and Google Maps API Web Services can be accessed over secure (HTTPS) connections by developers using EITHER the free version of these APIs or Google Maps API for Business.

Answer (score 12):

Yesterday Google announced that sites may use the v3 API for free over https:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing

```
http://maps.google.com/maps
```

with

```
https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps
```

Answer (score 1):

Google does allows https access for Maps API v3, Static Maps API, and Maps API Web Services.

But with [one](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html) condition:

> If your site uses SSL because you charge for access to your
>   application, or because your application is not publicly accessible to
>   all users, you must still purchase a Maps API Premier license.