# 404 Not Found error for all the Google Maps API V3 libraries

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting 404 Not Found error for all the Google Maps API libraries.

e.g. https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/main.js

The map works, when I build it through code but map does not load when I access the hosted website.

Comment: How are you including the file into your page/site/app?

Comment: No I have included only the Google maps API V3 url. It's making internal calls to the map libraries. Which is failing and hence maps is not showing up on my page.

Answer (score 1):

You should no longer use https://maps-api-ssl.google.com to access the API.  See [this blog post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2011/10/grab-bag-of-maps-api-news.html)

**Switch to googleapis.com**

The eagle eyed amongst you may have spotted that **we have updated all of our documentation to recommend that the Maps APIs be loaded from maps.googleapis.com rather than maps.google.com or maps-api-ssl.google.com**.  When loaded from maps.googleapis.com, the current implementation of the Maps API v3 does not rely on the exchange of cookies with Google. This improves both the security of the API, and the performance on bandwidth constrained networks. We therefore recommend all sites switch to using maps.googleapis.com.

Comment: Thank You for your response. But I am able to view the map when I launch the website using my Source code on Visual studio. There no library not found error. Could you please help me in understanding why is it working from source code but not with the hosted URL.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a certificate problem, try to access without https.

http://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/main.js

You can find more information about how get access with https in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756468/1845971

Regards.

Comment: I have Google Maps Premier customer access. Hence HTTPS should work for API V3. It works when I launch the website from my source code. But it's not loading and giving the libraries not found errors when I launch the URL.